# Subsonic Linq guid problem

Tags: linq, subsonic, guid

```
 The construtor 'Void .ctor(System.Guid, Int32)' is not supported.
```

this error occured with the following statements:

```
var Test = from r in db.UserRoles
  join p in db.UserPermissions
    on new { r.userId, r.roleId} equals new { p.userId, p.roleId }
  select r;
```

userId is a guid
roleId is an integer

Answer (score 1):

Right - the constructor for UserRoles looks like it needs a Guid and int - something you're not supplying explicitly. SubSonic has no way of figuring this out for you - one of the many reasons I keep telling people to abstract the membership stuff behind an interface and don't try to use SubSonic to get to it - you're circumventing most of their magic.

Comment: The workaround would be to use the MembershipProvider - or not. 

... yes, I'm really me.

Comment: dont be confused with the sample tables. my issue here is about the joining of two tables using 2 parameters in which one of the parameter is a Guid.

<code>
var Test = from r in db.Table1
  join p in db.Table2
    on new { r.aGuidColumn, r.intColumn} equals new { p.aGuidColumn, p.intColumn}
  select r;

</code>

Comment: My confusion on your problem has nothing to do with the validity of my answer :)

Comment: The membershipprovider you are talking about is far from my problem with guid.

Comment: The membershipprovider is the *exact* issue here. You need to supply values to the constructor in your projections - you can't do that with the code you've written.